# ASP.NET MVC 3 Remote validation to allow original value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I have a Remote attribute on the email property of my User model. When I create a new user, it works create and tells the users that an e-mail is already in use. Now I'm having a problem in my editing form (if the user wants to updates values). It tells the user that his/her e-mail is already in use, I don't want it to give that message when the e-mail that's in use is the one that's registered to the user. How can I tweak the Remote attribute to behave?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I figured it out.

In my view, I put `@Html.Hidden("InitialEmail", Model.Email)`

On my Model, I put `[Remote("IsEmailUsed", "User", AdditionalFields="InitialEmail")]`

And then in my controller action, I have `public JsonResult IsEmailUsed(string email, string initialEmail)` which will allow the initial e-mail to be valid.

Comment: have the same problem. nd i have done what you told but its not working. may i have the complete example of controller how you implement that