# How to handle Remote Attributes on Model Edit? ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, controller, action, remote-validation

I'm using Remote Attribute in my Model to check duplicate Page Titles as follows

```
public class Page
{
  [Remote("CheckDuplicate", "Page", ErrorMessage = "Title already taken")]
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And In controller, I'm returning **JsonResult** data based on "**Check**" result as follows:

```
public JsonResult CheckDuplicate(string Title)
{
   var result = db.Pages.Where(a => a.Title == Title).Count() == 0;
   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is working fine in **Create** action, But problem is, It's restricting me to Edit the Existing page, Since It's checking the same query.

How to solve this Problem? Please Suggest me something

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your question - can you elaborate on it? Why do you have a problem with your Edit view? And why is it a problem that the same remote validation is applied for both Create and Edit?

Comment: @Lasse Christiansen - sw_lasse: See Remote validation is applied on Model attribute **Title** So, whenever I operate on model, It Checks for this action.

Comment: @Lasse Christiansen - sw_lasse See, In Create form It checks for Duplicate title (returs true / false) this is okay. But in Edit for if I update with same Title, again it checks for Duplicate title with **"Title to be Edited"** and it says Title already taken. This is the Problem

Comment: I see, thanks - I have now posted a possible solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question looks similar to this: [ASP.NET MVC 3 Remote validation to allow original value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778151/asp-net-mvc-3-remote-validation-to-allow-original-value)

I think the trick is to use the `AdditionalFields` argument to your remote validation attribute in your model and combine that with a hidden field in your view - like suggested in the above StackOverflow post. Then you can send in the "initial" value along with the new value to your remote validation method and use both arguments to do your uniqueness check.

Another example of how to fix this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4756796/700926

The documentation for `AdditionalFields` can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute.additionalfields(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: What if you do not want to use it as a hidden field, but as an editable field ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be this way

You must have a hidden field in Edit page as `InitialUsername` and a `Remote` attribute on `User` model with `AdditionalFields` containing `InitialUsername`

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string UserName,string InitialUsername)
    {
        User user=null;
        //Check if user already exists
        if (UserName.Equals(InitialUsername)==false)
        {
         user = db.Users.Where(u => u.USERNAME == UserName).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        //

        return Json(user == null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add the Html attribute where you want to disable the remote validation
like

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CODE, 
                    new { 
                          htmlAttributes = new { 
                                                 @readOnly = true, 
                                                 @data_Val = false } })
```

and also see the HiddenField value if u stored 
It will be work

Answer (score 0):

i was solve using following steps:
In my view, I put `@Html.Hidden("InitialUserName", Model.UserName)`;

On Model put : `[Remote("IsUserNameUsed", "User", AdditionalFields="InitialUserName")]`

In Controller actionmethod write actionmethod as followiing :

```
    public JsonResult IsUserNameUsed(string UserName, string InitialUserName){
    bool isExist = true;
    if(UserName  != string.empty && InitialUserName == "undefined"){
    var isexist= db.model.where( x=>x.UserName == UserName).single();
    if(isexist != string.empty){
    bool isExist = false;
    }

    if(UserName  != string.empty && InitialUserName != "undefined"){
    var isexist= db.model.where( x=>x.UserName == UserName && x.UserName != InitialUserName ).single();
    if(isexist != string.empty){
    bool isExist = false;
    }    
return Json(isExist , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}    
}
```